# It does not remove the category from my datatable, I am using ajax, jquery, datatable, javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have this delete function in ajax, controller, model and a javascript and jquery code, I am trying to get the id_category with this, when I press delete it tells me that the category has been deleted but it is not deleted from my datatable and neither from my database data, does anyone know what the problem is? Here I leave my code.

```
`JavaScript:

$(document).on("click", ".btnEliminarCategoria", function() {
        var id_categoria = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var accion = $(this).data("accion");

        Swal.fire({
            title: '¿Está seguro de eliminar la categoría?',
            text: "¡Si no lo está, puede cancelar la acción!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: '¡Sí, eliminar categoría!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/categorias.ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        id_categoria: id_categoria,
                        accion: accion
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(respuesta) {
                        console.log(respuesta);
                        if (respuesta == "ok") {
                            Swal.fire(
                                '¡Eliminado!',
                                'La categoría ha sido eliminada.',
                                'success'
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });

Categorias.ajax:

<?php

require_once "../controladores/categoriascontrolador.php";
require_once "../modelos/categoriasmodelo.php";

class AjaxCategorias{

    public $idCategoria;
    public $Categoria;
    public $Descripcion;
public function ajaxEliminarCategoria(){

        $id = $_POST["id_categoria"];
        $accion = $_POST["accion"];
      
        if($accion == 1){
          $table = "categorias";
          $nameId = "id_categoria";
          $eliminar = CategoriasControlador::ctrEliminarCategoria($table, $id, $nameId);
          echo json_encode($eliminar);
        } else {
          echo json_encode("error");
        }
          
      }
}

if(isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] == 1){

    $eliminarProducto = new AjaxCategorias();
    $eliminarProducto -> ajaxEliminarCategoria();
}

Controller:

public static function ctrEliminarCategoria($table, $id, $nameId){

        $eliminar = CategoriasModelo::mdlEliminarCategoria($table, $id, $nameId);
                  
        return $eliminar;
}


Model:

static public function mdlEliminarCategoria($table, $id, $nameId){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $nameId = :$id");
          
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$nameId, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
        if($stmt -> execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
            $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
            return "Error al eliminar la categoría: " . $error[2];
        }
    }`
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or help.

Comment: Hi, can you post you PHP code in ```categorias.ajax.php``` or query as well.. that will help us understand issue better..

Comment: Hello, I already edited it, the ajax.categories, all the delete code is there, the ajax, controller and the model, together with the javascript code, I managed to solve something but it only deletes the name and the description of the category, but no It removes the ID or the creation date, I have not been able to solve the problem.